# Kendo UI Scheduler (timeline view) and event across midnight

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

Is there a way to setup Kendo UI Scheduler in timeline view to show a time span across midnight?
If startTime and endTime are in the same day all works fine, if I set two different days it show nothing

This is a two days example with custom view like you addressed
http://dojo.telerik.com/@purchased.software@deltatre.com/ihIzI

With this parameters it works fine

```
date: new Date("2016/4/18")
startTime: new Date("2016/4/18")
endTime: new Date("2016/4/19")
```

Also with these parameters

```
date: new Date("2016/4/18")
startTime: new Date("2016/4/18 8:00:00 AM")
endTime: new Date("2016/4/19 8:00:00 PM")
```

BUT with start hours (8PM) greather than end hours (8AM) it won't work

```
date: new Date("2016/4/18")
startTime: new Date("2016/4/18 8:00:00 PM")
endTime: new Date("2016/4/19 8:00:00 AM")
```

Comment: Just to make sure, are you trying to create an event across midnight or are you trying to display a range of hours that goes across midnight?

Comment: the second one "display a range of hours that goes across midnight"

Answer (score -1):

Look at my [jsfiddle](http://dojo.telerik.com/uWuZu). At current version of `kendo` that works perfectly, may be you use outdated version?

Here how it looks(with little arrow at corner when event is across midnight)
[image]

Comment: I have this problem with the timeline view

Comment: why downwote guy who try to help you? Select timeline view in dropdown in upper right corner

Comment: I already selected the timeline and only show a "full day", I need a time interval across two days